# What is the value of this Integration?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

What is the value of this :
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{{(\frac{1}{\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\sum_{b=0}^{\infty}\sum_{c=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a+b+c)!}})}x^{(\frac{1}{\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\sum_{b=0}^{\infty}\sum_{c=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a+b+c)!}})}}dx$$
My work:
we have
(1)..$$\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\sum_{b=0}^{\infty}\sum_{c=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a+b+c)!}=\frac{7e}{2}$$
and :
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha x^{\beta}}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha^n(-1)^n}{{(\beta n+1)}^{n+1}}$$
So $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{{(\frac{1}{\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\sum_{b=0}^{\infty}\sum_{c=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a+b+c)!}})}x^{(\frac{1}{\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\sum_{b=0}^{\infty}\sum_{c=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a+b+c)!}})}}dx=\int_{0}^{1}x^{(\frac{2}{7e}) x^{(\frac{2}{7e})}}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac{2}{7e})^n(-1)^n}{{((\frac{2}{7e}) n+1)}^{n+1}}$$
But$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac{2}{7e})^n(-1)^n}{{((\frac{2}{7e}) n+1)}^{n+1}}=?$$
You can help calculate the series or find an integral value in another way

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that this integral has a closed form in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: This problem is still worse than the somophore's dream.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)$~$0.919799786201$

Comment: Having a finite and well-defined value has nothing to do with whether the integral can be represented by known quantities. As Claude Leibovici pointed out in the comment, writing $S=\frac{7}{2}e$ for the sum and making the substitution $u=x^S$, the integral boils down to $$\frac{1}{S}\int_{0}^{1} u^{u-1+\frac{1}{S}}\,\mathrm{d}u,$$ which suffers the same issue as in the well-known Sophomore's Dream $$\int_{0}^{1}u^u\,\mathrm{d}u.$$ Even for this "easier" version, a closed form is still unknown (and likely not to exists).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici means ... this closed form is probably harder than $$\sum \frac{1}{n^n}$$but that closed form is unknown and many people have thought about it.